# Determining why an employee who is very quiet seems to be unhappy

Tags: management, software-development, morale, autism-spectrum

I manage a team of software developers.  I have an employee who is unusually antisocial. It's not just that he's quiet, he won't even nod to you if you pass him in the hall.  On the other hand, he is extremely productive. He's been with us for a few years and it's not an exaggeration to say that he does the work of three average developers. We DO NOT WANT to lose him.  For the past few weeks he's been unusually snippy with people and seems unhappy.  I need to determine if he's distressed about something at work or if there's something outside that has nothing to do with the company.

Changing his quiet behavior is not an option.  He is what he is.  He would not be pleased if I asked him if he's upset about something wrong outside of work.  In fact, he won't be pleased with me talking with him at all, but it has to be done.

Most people are money driven, but I have no reason to believe he's unhappy with his salary.  He's well (but not spectacularly) compensated, and due for another review in a few months.

I'm looking for a script I can use to determine if he's ok with his work, and if not, if there's something we can do to change that.  A script that doesn't seem too prying.  He will not be forthcoming, but I need to push it and determine if there's something we can do to change the situation.

Comment: This may be one of those rare occasions where emailing is better than talking.

Comment: Has his snippiness had any consequences (eg upset team-mates, someone decided not to ask him for something) or is it just a symptom you want to be sure is not a sign of a future issue that might occur?

Comment: @Owain As someone who's fairly quiet, I'd be much more inclined to open up in person than over email.

Comment: How responsive and engaging is he in conversations (specifically one-on-one conversations, and ideally more social less work-related ones)? Does he respond with the bare minimum for every single question or does he occasionally give more detailed responses and sometimes ask (optional) questions in return? Him not nodding to you in the hall doesn't say that much about how quiet he is (some people are just uncomfortable with that specific form of engagement).

Comment: What makes you say "he would not be pleased if I asked him if he's upset"? Is this an assumption just based on him being quiet or do you have a more specific reason to believe this?

Comment: Do you ever have one-on-one check-in sessions with people you manage?

Comment: might be relevant thread about autism: https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6090/april-is-autism-awareness-month

Comment: Since you say that " it's not an exaggeration to say that he does the work of three average developers" and "he's well (but not spectacularly) compensated," you may want to give better idea of how close his compensation is to 300% of the average developer's salary. This will allow those answering to be better informed.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I assume that the OP isn't going to read from a script but wants to plan the conversation ahead of time because they think there is a high chance of getting it wrong.

Comment: @KateGregory His snippiness doesn't have consequences because coworkers recognize that's just x being x.  Just want to be sure it's not a sign of him being unhappy at work.

Comment: @Dukeling How responsive is he in conversations: tends to give one or two word answers to any question.  Famously around here, once when asked if a set of deployment instructions are correct, he responded simply "no".

Comment: @Dukeling Why do I think he wouldn't be pleased if I asked him why he's upset: an assumption based on the fact he doesn't seem to like conversing with people in general.

Comment: @DKrueger Has received regular bumps in salary over the years.  Current salary is on the high end of a normal developer salary in our area - not a 3x salary.

Comment: @Dukeling ever have one-on-one check-in sessions with people you manage: I do not.  Speaking as someone being managed I haven't found them helpful, but that's probably something I should consider implementing.  If you have any hints or links about making one-on-ones more productive, I will check them out.

Comment: Does your workplace have access to an employee assistance program (EAP)? That could be an alternative if the employee doesn't want to discuss anything personal with you.

Comment: OT: *antisocial* means they want society to go away/be destroyed, ie. psychopathy. The proper term for introverted people is *asocial*

Comment: From the descriptions, it sounds like his compensation in terms of productivity may be near, or at, the bottom. I wouldn't perceive him as being well compensated--actually, the very opposite. If his perception is similar to mine, then money may be a serious problem. Don't be too quick to overlook that.

Answer (score 24):

**Non-expert opinion:**

Be direct about wanting to keep him and your willingness to be supportive. Don't address the worrying behaviour directly.

This allows you to communicate the information quickly, clearly, and with minimum fuss.

Something like...

> "Hi, I've brought you in for a quick one on one because we haven't had chance to catch up recently.
>
> I am (or: we are) really pleased with your work at the moment. Your work on [project x] is particularly good. Things are going well from my perspective but I'm keen to hear your perspective to make sure we are looking after you at work. Is there anything that I can do to help support you?"
>
> [employee most likely gives no useful response, says that everything is fine]
>
> "Ok, that's good to hear. Have a think about it and if you do think of anything please let me know and we'll try to get it sorted out for you."

The idea is to make it clear that they are a valued employee and that you are approachable if and when they have a problem. You might be able to achieve more by tackling the problem head on but it would be a much trickier conversation to handle.

Comment: If the productive employee was upset with a recent change his manager made (ie. he was upset at his manager), his manager might not be the best person to have that conversation with. If there were multiple levels of management maybe the second line manager might be able to glean more insight?

Answer (score 3):

You're probably correct that he doesn't want to talk about whatever it is. But that doesn't mean you can't still broach the topic. Just be careful not to pry, and be as supportive as you can be.

- Thank him for his stellar work.
- Tell him that you noticed a recent change in his behaviour. (He probably realizes people will notice.)
- Ask him if everything's okay. (He'll probably say yes, even if it isn't true.)
- Don't press him for details, and do tell him that it's up to him to talk about it whenever he wants to.

Then offer him time off to deal with whatever it is, working from home, or shorter work hours. Whatever he needs. Don't just thank him verbally for his efforts, but show your appreciation by being supportive. (If it's at all in your power, try to convince your boss to allow your most valuable employee a temporary reduction in work time without any pay cut or increased workload at a later point. If you can manage to keep him, it'll pay off in the long run.)

Disclaimer: I recently experienced the situation from the other perspective, where I was the valuable employee and needed a temporary reduction in work time. It's not at all the same as I was entirely open about the reasons, but having my manager sign that off without the topic of a pay cut even entering the conversation sure did make me feel appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Is there actually a problem for your company? He is "snippy" and "seems unhappy", but is that actually a problem? People are unhappy sometimes. He might be snippy and unhappy because his cat died. There is no indication that he is unhappy with his work.

If he has a problem that is in no way work related, and you try to find out what is going on, you might actually be creating a work related problem. At least give it some time. I would recommend that your best plan for action would be to do nothing.

Comment: If it is work related, and they do not address it and do nothing to improve the situation, the employee may move to another company.

Comment: If it is not work related and the do something because SOMETHING MUST BE DONE, the employee may also move to a different company because the are pissed if by an interfering boss. And if it’s work related, they can leave anyway.

Comment: Also if it's not work related, the guy might still move. You know, because he's fed up with the traffic jams, or he wants to relocate to Stratford.

Answer (score -3):

> "Do you feel too much is being expected from you?  I really don't know you, but it seems to me your productivity is off the charts. So I'm actually concerned, really just guessing for the moment, that it will be very tough, and even unnecessary, to keep up that pace for the long term.
>
> So if this, or something else, is becoming an issue for you I want to make it very clear, and very safe, that you have as much opportunity, perhaps even personal obligation, to have it discussed.
>
> I'd frankly rather have happy employees that feel they have a long-term home than employees who equate production with success at the cost of their health."

Comment: hi. Could you provide reasons this script is going to achieve what OP wants? right now it lacks context

Comment: @aaaaaa Sure. The way to find out what an unsocial person is to ask them.

But since the person is unsocial you have to assume they have a fear ... so you have to give them them permission to behave in a way that may be helpful to both. 

The person is afraid of being fired ... of doing something wrong ... why does one person do the work of three, for fun?

Comment: @RandyZeitman Some people can do 3 times the work others can do in the same amount of time. I don't see anything else in the question to suggest they're working any longer or harder than anyone else (although that may be something to ask for clarification about). Also, this speech is assuming this is about them working too hard and mostly running with that, without asking any input from them, instead of having an open-minded discussion about what the actual problem is. I'm just me, but that approach would make me fairly uncomfortable and not receptive whether they're right or not.

Comment: @Dukeling  You seem to be saying the opposite of what I wrote. I'm very blunting stating we do *not* know if you're working too hard. (And yes, a person doing three times more would be working harder ... what else could it mean.)

Comment: @RandyZeitman I should explain, it's not that he works 3x the hours.  In fact he works fewer hours than most devs.  He's just smart, VERY focused and fast.

Comment: Yes, that's how I see it. My script makes no statement about hours.

Comment: @RandyZeitman "I'm very blunting stating we do not know if you're working too hard" - sure, but if they're *not* working too hard, the second, third and fifth sentences wouldn't be at all relevant.

Comment: @Dukeling  If you think a person can do the job of three and not work any more hours or any more intensely, assuming each of those 'three people' not terrible slackers actually doing 1/3rd their job, then I think it's quite safe to assume the person in question is working more ... whether that means time or intensity.

Comment: @RandyZeitman Would you also say a body builder casually lifting 15 kg weights is doing a more intense workout than a child struggling to lift 5 kg weights? And why would higher intensity be a problem anyway? Are you suggesting doing your best for an average number of work hours is unhealthy and unsustainable?

Comment: @Dukeling  You seem to be introducing issues that not related to issue originally posted.